# How to refresh Vertical scrollbar in VirtualStringTree?

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

how to refresh the scrollbar of `VirtualStringTree` if each nodeheight was changed into different Height. coz, the scroll are still in the same state causing other node cannot be viewed when scrolled.

`toVariableNodeHeight` option will not work? any other idea?

Comment: Look for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839397/how-to-reliably-scroll-virtual-treeview-to-the-bottom/2840080#2840080 question and answer. Could be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something tells me that when you say "each NodeHeight was changed," you really mean to say that you assigned new values directly to the `NodeHeight` field of each of the node records. First of all, don't do that. If you must assign heights to nodes, assign them through the tree's `NodeHeight` property. That is, instead of this:

```
{*} Node.NodeHeight := x;
```

Do this:

```
Tree.NodeHeight[Node] := x;
```

That will automatically adjust the cached heights of all the node's ancestors, which is what determines the scroll-bar range.

Better yet, don't assign heights to nodes at all. Instead, handle the tree's `OnMeasureItem` event, where the tree asks you how tall each node is. That event is fired when you have the `toVariableNodeHeight` option set.

If you really insist on skipping the tree's node-height management, then you need to make sure you handle *all* the necessary tasks yourself. That includes updating not only the `NodeHeight` field but also the `TotalHeight` field of the node, its parent, its grandparent, and so on until you've set the total height of the hidden root node. See `TBaseVirtualTree.AdjustTotalHeight` for details. It has private visibility, so you can't call it yourself.

`OnMeasureItem` will only get called once for a node. If you need it to be called again because the node's contents have changed and you need the tree to re-measure the height, then call `ReinitNode`. If you're using `TCustomVirtualStringTree`, you can also call `InvalidateNode`.