# TVirtualTreeView with rows of variable height: scrolling artefacts

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, virtualtreeview

I am using the [VirtualTreeView](https://code.google.com/p/virtual-treeview/) together with the `OnMeasureItem` event to display rows of variable size. The problem is that the event seems to be called only if a row is painted (following the virtual paradigm). But this leads to the scrollbar being displayed incorrectly. If I scroll to the bottom (by dragging the scrollbox with the mouse, not clicking the scroll buttons at the top or bottom), not the last row is displayed (which is what I would expect), but some row in the middle. After that, the scrollbar is updated and I can scroll further down. It seems as if the component uses the `DefaultNodeHeight` for its scrolling calculations. But since my rows have variable height, I cannot specify a `DefaultNodeHeight` that would lead to correct results. Option `toVariableNodeHeight` is enabled.

Has anyone experienced this before and maybe found a workaround? Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Just for sure. Do you have `toVariableNodeHeight` option included in the `TreeOptions.MiscOptions` set, do you ? Could you include this information into your question as well as the version of VirtualTreeView are you using, please ?

Comment: `toVariableNodeHeight` makes no difference - I tried both. I am on revision 431 which is from november 2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `DefaultNodeHeight` to the maximum value you will be using and `OnMeasureItem` event set custom height value for the current node. Similar issue was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839397/how-to-reliably-scroll-virtual-treeview-to-the-bottom/2840080#2840080).

Comment: Thank you very much!! I just set it to some upper bound value and it works perfectly.